# PowerMock access private static members

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

How I can access the following private static field foo by PowerMock. I just want to verify that Foo for example is not null and I can't refactor the code by adding getters.

```
public class Bar{

   private static Foo foo = new Foo();


}
```

I try to use this but it does not work:

```
Foo foo = Whitebox.getInternalState(bar, "foo");
```

Comment: Try `Whitebox.getInternalState(Bar.class, "foo")`?

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot

Comment: I noticed that you didn't accept any answer yet. Please consider doing that at some point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Whitebox.getInternalState(Foo.class, "FIELD_NAME");
```

Answer (score 1):

Verifying that a private field has a certain content translates to: testing internal implementation details. Sure, that is possible, but it also makes your tests very fragile - slight changes (like: refactoring) to the production code, and your tests fail; although you probably did not change the **contract** of your class under test.

And you see - I am pretty sure that it **somehow** makes a difference within your class under test if that field is null or not. Meaning: some behavior your class under test will be different for those two scenarios.

Thus my suggestion: see if you can avoid Powermock here - by finding **other** ways to "assert" something within your production class to test if that field is null.

Seriously: if the content of that field doesn't influence *any* observable behavior of your class under test - what would be the purpose of that field in the first place?!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring's [ReflectionTestUtils.getField()](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html#getField-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-) for that:

```
Foo foo = ReflectionTestUtils.getField(Bar.class, "foo");
```

Comment: OP's question is not related to Spring at all.